# LNK2005 error, function is defined in .obj

Tags: c++, qt

this is my first question on this forum so i'm sorry for the format with the code-inclusion already.

I have a LNK2005 Error occuring with my little Project i am working on, most other questions on SOF and other pages in the web were answered with the wrong inclusion of a .cpp code in another .cpp code or a doubled inclusion of a .h code snippet. Although that helped other people I only have 2 headers, both included only in their respective .cpp and the main.cpp. Basically the other posts are o help to me because I did not include headers multiple times or defined anything in them or included .cpps

My Code:

eingabefeld.h

```
#ifndef EINGABEFELD_H
#define EINGABEFELD_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class eingabefeld;
}

class eingabefeld : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit eingabefeld(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~eingabefeld();


signals:
    void signal_taste(char);


private:
    Ui::eingabefeld *ui;
};

#endif // EINGABEFELD_H
```

uebung.h

```
#ifndef UEBUNG_H
#define UEBUNG_H
#include <QMainWindow>


namespace Ui {
class uebung;
}

class uebung : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit uebung(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~uebung();


public slots:
     void signals_taste(char taste);

private:
    Ui::uebung *ui;
};

#endif // UEBUNG_H
```

eingabefeld.cpp

```
#include "eingabefeld.h"
#include "ui_eingabefeld.h"

eingabefeld::eingabefeld(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::eingabefeld)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

eingabefeld::~eingabefeld()
{
    delete ui;
}



void eingabefeld::signal_taste(char taste)
{

}
```

uebung.cpp

```
#include "uebung.h"
#include "ui_uebung.h"


uebung::uebung(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::uebung)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

uebung::~uebung()
{
    delete ui;
}

void uebung::signals_taste(char taste)
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "eingabefeld.h"
#include "uebung.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    uebung w;
   /*
    w.show();
   */
    eingabefeld e;
    e.show();
    QObject::connect(&e,SIGNAL(on_textEdit_textChanged(char)),&w,SLOT(on_textEdit_textChanged(char)));


    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared eingabefeld's `on_textEdit_textChanged` signals and uebung's `on_textEdit_textChanged` slot?

Comment: ah i missed renaming those. I tried out some different ways to fixing this problem, one was that maybe those premade functions from the qt creator may be blocking the programm. I just tried it out with now the right names. It still does not work.